# my opencart checkout page show,internal server error

Tags: opencart, checkout, payumoney

i was trying to integrate zoho email with my opencart website,as my hostgator team suggested,to point to the domain first,so it was already did,so i deleted an old one and point again to zoho,and after that pointing thing,my payumoneys stop working.

i am really sure,that i didn`t delete anyfile from anywhere,but still got internal server error,i don`t get it why is this happening,this is my first time to integrate payment gateway with opencart,somebody please give me some,solution for this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeBko.jpg)

Comment: internal server error???  you should check on your server what error? If you do not have access, ask your server provider regarding this error.

Comment: I had check with my server team,they said nothing is wrong with the server,may be there is some code is missing

Comment: The server can be working fine, but if you facing some internal server error they should collect this errors on the  error log on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've switched your mail settings in OpenCart from "mail" to "SMTP" and tried to configure Zoho?

If the SMTP settings are wrong it could throw an error at the checkout and if your server is not configured to display errors these will appear in the error log only - not on the page.

You should try switching back to "mail" to see if that solves the issue and that would then confirm the above diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks Paul,Works for me thank you so much,really appreciate your help,i was stuck because of this stupid issue around 2 weeks and i didn`t notice to turn off smtp, ok will you please helpme out with one more thing,how do i integrate zoho email with opencart, how to do it, as you already know because of smtp my payment gateway stop working, so is there any suggestion you can give,will really help me out,please reply soon

Comment: My pleasure Anuj, I'm always glad when I can help! Please upvote the answer and mark as the accepted solution, then ask a new question about integrating Zoho with OpenCart.

Comment: already did, my opencart website icons,is not showing on homepage mostly,what to do,will you please help me little bit more

Comment: Please provide a link to that question.

Comment: No, to the *question*.